# Question regarding elementary trigonometry and movement

Tags: trigonometry

If we have two objects with coordinates $O_1(x_1, y_1)$ and $O_2(x_2, y_2)$, and we wanted to move $O_1$ to $O_2$, we could do so in a discrete way using the equations

$$x_i=v\cos{\theta}$$
$$y_i=v\sin{\theta}$$

where $x_i$ and $y_i$ are the respective distances we increment $x_1$ and $y_1$ every unit of time, $v$ is the velocity at which we move $O_1$, and $\theta$ is the angle between $O_1$ and $O_2$.

When we dissect the equations with the standard "SOH, CAH, TOA" definitions we have

$$x_i=\frac{\Delta{x}}{d}v$$
$$y_i=\frac{\Delta{y}}{d}v$$

where $d$ is the distance between $O_1$ and $O_2$ and $\Delta{x}$ and $\Delta{y}$ are the horizontal and vertical distances between $O_1$ and $O_2$, respectively. This makes sense to me. Since we are performing the same operations on $\Delta{x}$ and $\Delta{y}$, our slope stays the same and we move in the direction of $O_2$. We can say $\frac{1}{d}$ and $v$ are "increment factors". That is, they affect how far we move in each increment. Without them, we simply move from $O_1$ to $O_2$ in one increment.

$v$ as an increment factor makes sense to me. But, why is $\frac{1}{d}$(the other increment factor) the "correct" increment factor? I know these are the rules in trigonometry, but why can't we simply have an increment factor of, say, $\frac{1}{5}$? Or no increment factor at all? The effect remains the same. $O_1$ moves to $O_2$ and we can adjust velocity $v$ to slow/speed up the process.

Comment: I think you have defined $x_i \ $ and $d \ $ well. But what is your definition of $ \Delta x ?$

Comment: $\Delta{x}=x_2-x_1$. The same goes for $y$.

Comment: Also, I should note that these "objects" can be treated as points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to view your equation $$x_i=\frac{\Delta{x}}{d}v$$

as $$x_i=S\Delta{x}$$

with "increment scale factor" $ \ S =  \frac{v}{d}, \ $ so let's go ahead and do this.

Below is a diagram based on your definitions of the different variables.

[image]

If you didn't already know, in the diagram, triangles $ABC \ $ and $O_1 O_2 D$ are similar right-angled triangles. Angle $ O_2 O_1 D \ $ = angle $ \ BAC = \theta$.

$x_i $ is the horizontal distance moved in 1 second. Suppose $x_i = 10 \ m$.
Also, notice that the distance moved in 1 second in the direction of motion from $O_1$ to $O_2$ is $v \ m$ because that's the distance an object travelling at $v \ m/s $ moves in $ 1 \ second $.

If $d = 1 \ million \ km, \ $ then of course the scale factor that gets you from $ \ x_i \ $ to $ \ \Delta{x} \ $ is going to have something to to with the large distance d. In fact the scale factor you have to multiply each side of triangle $ABC$ to make it into triangle $0_1 0_2 D$ is $ d/v, \ $ again, you can think of $v$ as the distance from A to B if your unit of time increment is $1s$. So to get from large triangle $0_1 0_2 D$ to small triangle $ABC, \ $ you have to multiple by scale factor $ \frac{d}{v}$.

If it takes $1 \ second \ $ to move from A to B, then it takes $ \frac{d}{v} \ seconds \ $ to move from $0_1$ to $0_2$

Comment: Technically assumes no acceleration. But I'm mostly being annoying.

Comment: His question felt like a constant velocity one. He didn't mention acceleration.

Comment: Yes, constant velocity

Comment: Also, I'm a little confused as to what you are communicating in your answer. It may be because of my own inexperience. From the way I'm looking at it, you explain how triangle $ABC$ can be scaled up to triangle $O_1O_2D$ using the scale factor $\frac{d}{v}$. I'm having trouble connecting this with my question. Again, because of my inexperience with math.

Comment: I thought that was the heart of your question. What exactly is your question then? And please be clear.

Comment: In short, I want to know exactly why we are dividing by $d$ in the equations in my question. Without the division by $d$ ($d=1$), we can simply adjust velocity $v$ to speed up/slow down with the movement of $O_1$ to $O_2$. We move in the correct direction because the ratio of $x_i$ to $y_i$ remains the same (slope).

Comment: You can adjust $v$ in your equations regardless if your equation is $x_i = v \Delta x$ or $x_i = \frac{v}{d} \Delta x$. The difference between the two equations is that the first one is wrong and the second one is right. d is just a constant because $O_1$ and $O_2$ are fixed, and d is just the distance between them. To see why the first equation is wrong and the second one is right, you should try different values of the variables and see which equation works/makes sense.